# Reading adjacent columns data apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel file as shown below -

```
 - Sales SalesD    Product ProductD       Company CompanyD           - Row0
 - Cars     120       Tires   125         XYZ     130                - Row1
 - Trucks   160       Oil     165         ABC     160                - Row2
```

I have to read the file as follows taking two adjacent columns data at a time. Read (Row0, Cell0, Row0, Cell1) (Row1, Cell1, Row1, Cell2) and so on till first two rows are done and read 3, 4 same way.

```
Read Sales , then read SalesD and store Sales = SalesD
Read Cars, then read 120 and store Cars=120
Read Trucks then read 160 and store Trucks=12
```

When these two columns are finished reading , then do the same with Product ProductData, then Company CompanyData.

Please help me read such a file in apache poi. Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything ?? and why you want to read in that format ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a POJO class for the excel format. Let's say class ABC.

```
class ABC{
    String sales; //(For Sales)
    String product; //(For Product)
    String company; //(For Company)
}
```

Now while reading the excel row-wise, all you have to do is create an ArrayList of this POJO, create an object of this POJO and assign values when an odd index is found. The values for Car, Trucks, etc. would be stored in a string format. You can convert them into integers when you want to use them.